# Content filter function not working... Can't find bug

Tags: swift, xcode, filter

I've been messing with a content filter system in XCode 6 Playground in Swift and the idea is that if I input a string with multiple words (Ex: "Apple Oranges Bananas"), the function will separate this string into an array then cycle through the database with any of these words and should return true if there is a match. So my function returns true if I put a whole word but returns false when I put a single letter... I used the "RangeOfString" line so it should go through the word character by character but i don't know.. Really stumped.

Here is the code..

```
    // Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class Person {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0

    init(name: String, age:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

var filteredItems = [Person]()

var items = [ Person(name: "Anders", age: 23), Person(name: "Alice", age: 56), Person(name: "Amanda", age: 88)]

items.append(Person(name: "Andrew", age: 23))

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText : String) -> Bool
{
    var filtered = false

    //Filter the array using the filter method
    filteredItems = items.filter({( search : Person) -> Bool in

        let stringMatch = queryValidator(searchText, search.name)
        let intMatch = queryValidator(searchText, String(search.age))

        filtered = (stringMatch != false || intMatch != false)
        return (stringMatch != false || intMatch != false)
    })
    return filtered
}

func queryValidator(search : String, database : String) -> Bool
{
    //Function that splits search query into multiple querys
    let query = search.uppercaseString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    var queryFound = false

    for(var i = 0; i < query.count; i++)
    {
        let match = query[i].uppercaseString.rangeOfString(database.uppercaseString)

        if(match != nil)
        {
            queryFound = true
        }
    }

    return queryFound
}


filterContentForSearchText("a")
```

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string.rangeOfString does not do a prefix match. So if you search with "a", you don't have any people in your array with a name that is "a". If you want to do prefix match, try using String.hasPrefix (as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I used the hasPrefix method instead and it works wonders with what I needed. :)